Which deep learning model: CNN or VGG16 based on metrics and accuracy plots?
I trained two models using for image classification: one with a CNN (dataset 1 was significantly cropped to separate shaded and non-shaded images, 100 epochs) and the other with VGG16 transfer learning (dataset 1 was slightly cropped with both shaded and non-shaded areas in an image, 50 epochs). I saved the best models based on the highest accuracy and lowest loss values for each method. For the CNN, I achieved a loss of 0.47 and an accuracy of 0.88, while the VGG16 model had a loss of 0.11 and an accuracy of 0.98. The accuracy plots over epochs indicate over-fitting for both models (with red representing training and green representing validation).
Given these results, I know the VGG16 model appears to be the better choice. However, I noticed that the accuracy plot for the CNN shows smooth convergence, whereas the VGG16 plot exhibits more fluctuation. Should I take these accuracy plots into consideration? Which model would be recommended based on the evaluation metrics and accuracy plots?
CNN model

VGG16 model

I appreciate any help in advance.
Abbas
